# If statement not accepting the condition

Tags: php, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

i have form with personal details need to be submitted and received by email.
I am passing few if condition not to have my empty form. But it doesn't  seems to work.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$SuccessRedirect    = 'sucessfully_submitted.html';
$to         ='sanaullahkhan81@gmail.com';
$name       =$_POST['name'];
$email      =$_POST['email'];
$ph_name        =$_POST['phone'];
$model      =$_POST['model'];
$imei       =$_POST['imei'];
$message    =$_POST['message'];
$subject    ='Customer Phone Details for Selling from:  '.$name ;

$actul_msg  ='A Message from Contact Us Page'. "\n".'Name: '.$name."\n".' Eamil: 
'.$email."\n" .'Phone Name:'.$ph_name."\n".'Model:'.$model."\n".'IMEI No:'.$imei."\n".' 
Message: '.$message;

if(!empty($name) || !empty($email) || !empty($ph_name) || !empty($model) || !empty($imei))

{
mail($to,$subject,$actul_msg);
header('Location: '.$SuccessRedirect);
}
else
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("A Name:, Email:, Message: is required "); 
</script>';
include('quote.html');
}
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

[Click here to check online](http://epbuys.co.uk/quote.html)

Comment: You are using || which is stating "if the name is NOT empty OR the email is not empty..."

Answer (score 1):

Change || to && the validation is wrong

```
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($ph_name) &&  !empty($model) &&  !empty($imei))
```

Comment: [check this out Online](http://epbuys.co.uk/quote.html)

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
  if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($ph_name) && !empty($model) && !empty($imei)){

  }
```

or this-

```
 if($name!="" && $email!="" && $ph_name!="" && $model!="" && $imei!=""){

  }
```

Comment: [check this out Online](http://epbuys.co.uk/quote.html) it doesnt work `if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($ph_name) && !empty($model) && !empty($imei))`

Comment: I have edited the ans. If that does not work either please check your variables by echo-ing.

Comment: Thanks guys i just removed '//ob_start();', and '//ob_end_clean();', worked fine

Answer (score 1):

You should use `&&`

Try this:

```
if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($ph_name) && !empty($model) && !empty($imei)) {

}
```

or

```
if (!(empty($name) && empty($email) && empty($ph_name) && empty($model) && empty($imei))) {

}
```

Comment: still does not work after changing, [check it out Online](http://epbuys.co.uk/quote.html),

Answer (score 0):

The || is called the OR operator. It checks if the statement on the left OR the statement on the right(or both) is true, then it returns true. The AND operator(&&) returns ony true if the BOTH statements are true.

Your code will run the commands inside the if when one ore more of your statemsnts are true.
Ex: if $name is not empty, it will run the code in the if, altought the other statemsnts can be false or true.

This code will only run the code inside the if when all statements are true:

```
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($ph_name) &&  !empty($model) &&  !empty($imei)) {
   //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks `if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($ph_name) &&  !empty($model) &&  !empty($imei))` using this still does not work

Comment: are you sure that the vars aren't empty?

Comment: [check this out Online](http://epbuys.co.uk/quote.html) , still does not work

Comment: try if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($ph_name) ||  empty($model) ||  empty($imei)) { /*error handling here*/ } else { /*Mail here*/ }

Comment: yes did but no luck, [Check this web site link](http://epbuys.co.uk/quote.html)

Comment: I am wondering is it something to do with my button which is css made not a submit type

Comment: yes, saw your site, think the form is correct. Have you tryed to put an echo 'Test'; before your mail function? (maybe the mail() function is the problem) I think your button works, because you said, you got the values from post, havn't you? Or try a var_dump($_POST); to check the post values.

Comment: Thanks guys i just removed 'ob_start();', and 'ob_end_clean();', worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys i just removed '//ob_start();', and '//ob_end_clean();', worked fine